# Express-Session not working on production when on Incognito Mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, session-cookies, express-session

I am using express-session to handle user sessions. The problem is when I'm on incognito mode in production it doesn't work. I use heroku to deploy my node js application.

On localhost I use this and it works on both normal and incognito mode.

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 100,
    },
  })
);
```

But once deployed, I use the code below since the top doesn't work on production and doesn't set the cookie. Now this works and sets the cookie but not on incognito mode.

```
app.use(   session({
    store: store,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    proxy: true, 
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 48,
      sameSite: "none",
    },   }) );
```

I found a similar problem but has no answers:
[Express Session is not working in production on incognito mode but everything working fine locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369834/express-session-is-not-working-in-production-on-incognito-mode-but-everything-wo)

**EDIT**

After hours of searching. I think this problem has something to do with how heroku handles cookies if sent from a different from a different domain eg: [www.my-front-end.netlify.app](http://www.my-front-end.netlify.app) requests api from [www.my-heroku-backend.app](http://www.my-heroku-backend.app) If someone on incognito allows third party cookies, then the problem will be solved. I may be wrong please feel free to correct me. Thanks everyone. For more info check:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com

TLDR: Heroku sends third party cookies. Incognito blocks third party cookies thus the error is created.

Comment: You have to provide more details, like do you see the session cookie being sent along with requests? There's nothing inherently different in incognito mode that would prevent sessions to not work, other than (obviously) sessions being destroyed once you close the last incognito window/tab. It could also be a sign that your backend code isn't actually working properly, but that some leftover session data stored during a "regular" session (not incognito) makes it look like it does. Have you removed all cookies for your domain prior to testing if it actually works?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I added more details. I hope it helps.

Comment: I think you need to set `app.set('trust proxy', 1)` for your app because you are using `secure: true`.

Comment: Hello. the  " proxy: true, " acts like that but I also did what you said and it's still the same. It seems like not blocking third-party cookies will enable my website in incognito to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, express session will be like a map stored inside the express instance running context..
Every request will be validated against the existence of an entry in that map..
In local you are running a single instance of express server...

That may not be the case in heroku instance.. there should be multiple instances of your express server running behind the proxy.

So.. your session creation request posted to instance_1 and it responded back with a cookie to refer an entry it's internal session map..

And further request got forwarded by the proxy to a different express instance say instance_2 which doesn't know anything about the session created inside instance_1.

So it returns 401 and makes your session inconsistent.

There are ways to store db in a common DBs.like an external mongo.

Please google and Try that..